# Set hosts value with an extra-vars doesn't work for my Ansible role

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I've got a problem with my ansible playbook :

**My playbook is composed of 5 roles and looks like this :**

```
---
- name: Création de la machine virtuelle {{ Host_Name }} à l'aide du template {{ vcenter_template }}
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  roles:
  - roles/VMWare/deploy
  tags: deploy

- name: Configuration de l'échange de clé de root@lrtstfpe vers root@{{ Host_Name }}
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  roles:
  - roles/VMWare/pre_config
  tags: pre_config

- name: Opérations post install
  hosts: '{{ Host_Name }}'
  gather_facts: no
  roles:
  - roles/VMWare/post_install
  tags: post_install

- name: Ajout du pointeur DNS sur le controleur de domaine wpsrvctldom1.uem.lan
  hosts: DNS
  gather_facts: no
  roles:
  - roles/DNS/
  tags: DNS

- name: Ajout du mot de passe Keepass de l'utilisateur root de la machine
  hosts: DNS
  gather_facts: no
  roles:
  - roles/Keepass/
  tags: keepass
```

**I launch this playbook with this command :**

```
ansible-playbook playbook/deployVM.yml --extra-vars "Host_Name=toto"
```

My variable is correctly interpreted in my tasks name but my third role which use the value of this variable to do operations on the appropriate host is skipped and Ansible says "`skipping: no hosts matched`".

But when I re-launch my playbook with "`--tags post_install`" to play only this role... **It works !**

I don't know why when I launch the entire playbook it doesn't work and when I launch just the 3rd role.. It works..

Can someone help me ?

Thx :)

PS : I add my `{{ Host_Name }}` machine into `/etc/ansible/hosts` file thanks to the 2nd role :

```
[VM]
toto
```

Comment: "PS : I add my {{ Host_Name }} machine into /etc/ansible/hosts file thanks to the 2nd role" does that mean before that 2nd role runs, the `toto` hostname isn't known to ansible? Because if so, I think you'll need to _also_ use [`add_host:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/modules/add_host_module.html#add-host-module) to teach the in-memory ansible about the host

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ansible reads the `/etc/ansible/hosts` or any other inventory file before starting the playbook. It is not read again during(or between) the plays. You are populating the hosts' file during the play and then trying to read in the next play; which will not work. You have to add the dynamically created host using [add_host](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/add_host_module.html) to playbook's in-memory inventory.

If you don't want to explicitly `add_host` then there is another way to [refresh inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/meta_module.html). You have to invoke meta module to refresh inventory before the play which requires the updated inventory.

**Example**:

```
- name: Re-read inventory files
  meta: refresh_inventory
```

Comment: Thank you @Kanwar Saad, 

Your example solved my problem !

Comment: Glad that it helped .. can you accept my answer also